# Differences between OCI-C and OCI?

Tags: cloud, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Oracle has the same services on their new platform Oracle Cloud Infrastructure ([OCI](https://cloud.oracle.com/en_US/cloud-infrastructure)) and Oracle Cloud Infrastructure - Classic ([OCI-C](https://cloud.oracle.com/en_US/classic)).

What are the differences between these two platforms? Do the hypervisors differ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both OCI and OCI-C are platforms for IaaS.

## OCI-C

- formerly called Oracle Public Cloud (OPC)
- Based on [Xen hypervisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xen)
- Offers VMs only
- Elastic of Dedicated Compute

## OCI

- Essentially a rebranding of Oracle's Bare Metal Cloud Service (BMCS)
- Hypervisor based on [KVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine)
- Offers VMs and [Bare Metal](https://cloud.oracle.com/compute/bare-metal/features) compute
- Compute, Availability Domain, Virtual Cloud Network, and Edge deployment

There's also Cloud at Customer (C@C or just CC) where you "subscribe" to the cloud services but the servers are kept on the customer's premises.

Comment: Hi Steven, Can you answer this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62464072/difference-between-iam-idcs-and-oci-in-oracle-cloud

Answer (score 1):

To add on to that, OCI now has tons of services. Check out their status page for more https://ocistatus.oraclecloud.com/ I think this one is still missing services like service gateway.

Answer (score 0):

From https://blogs.oracle.com/generation-2:-oracle-cloud-infrastructure

One can think of the first-generation cloud as built for cloud native, net-new applications. Gen 2 cloud infrastructure is excellent for those use cases as well, but it also enables enterprises to replace on-premises data centers with a cloud deployment model.

Oracle Cloud Infrastructure is Oracle’s gen 2 cloud infrastructure, and it’s what we’re building and operating today. It’s purpose-built for the enterprise and couldn’t have been built 10 years ago or 5 years ago, from both an architecture and an open-source-capabilities perspective.

Oracle Cloud Infrastructure is available globally, and it has the feature set, the capabilities, and the differentiation to run all the mission-critical, high-volume, high-performance data­bases and workloads for the world’s most demanding enterprises. Oracle Cloud Infrastructure is ready for any and all workloads.