# Difference between IAM , IDCS and OCI in Oracle cloud

Tags: oracle, cloud, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am getting confused on these 3 terms. What I know `OCI` is infrastructure provided by Oracle, `IAM` is user and `IDCS` is Identity cloud service. But I dont understand  differences and terms.

```
Is IAM user and normal user are same?

is OCI and IDCS are same?

What exactly IDCS is?
```

Comment: Where did you see this question? It sounds like they're test questions, in which case we want to consider what the writer of the test was trying to ascertain.

Comment: They are not the test question Steven. I have to migrate my on-premise infrastructure to cloud so during presentation these questions came.

Comment: Ohh, how technical is your audience?

Comment: They are DBAs and Developers. They will understand technical terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all

OCI refer to Oracle Cloud infrastructure and it's cloud computing solutions same as MS azure or amazon AWS, but offered by Oracle and it's providing various services such as servers, storage, network, applications and services through a global network of Oracle Corporation managed by different data center around the world.

IAM refer to Identity and Access Management this is services allow you to control who can access to cloud resource and even control what type of access they have, and to which specific resource, there is different Components of IAM such as resource, user, group and more you can check Oracle documentation that provide also examples [here](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Identity/Concepts/overview.htm)

IDCS refer to Oracle Identity Cloud Service and it's consider as  Identity-as-a-Service (IDaaS) solution, Oracle Identity Cloud Service provides identity management, single-sign-on (SSO) and identity governance for applications on-premise, in the cloud and mobile applications , Any user can access the application at any time, anywhere on a device in a secure manner. Oracle IDCS integrates directly with existing directories and identity management system, making it easier for users to access applications. Providing a platform that is robust and secure, allows users to access, develop and deploy their applications.

Check the documentation [here](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/middleware/oracle-identity-cloud-service.html)

The benefits of implementing Oracle Identity Cloud Service are; Improved Business Responsiveness, Enhanced User Productivity and Experience, Hybrid Multi-Channel Access and finally Simplified IT and Reduced Cost.

Answer (score 8):

Let me try to answer your questions:

IAM or Identity Access Management is a tool designed to control who access to your cloud services. IAM user is an user who access to a service in your Cloud. What do you mean by normal user I cannot know.

OCI or Oracle Cloud Infrastructure, is a deep and broad platform of cloud services that enable you to build and run a wide range of applications in a scalable, secure, highly available, fault-tolerant and high-performance environment.

Oracle Identity Cloud Service (IDCS) is an Identity-as-a-Service (IDaaS) solution available in Oracle Cloud. It is designed to extend enterprise controls by automating PaaS and SaaS account provisioning and deprovisioning, simplifying the user experience for accessing cloud applications by providing seamless integration with enterprise identity stores and authentication services, and facilitating compliance activities by clearly reporting on cloud application usage.

Although it look like IDCS and IAM might look the same, they are designed to different purposes. IDCS is focused on SaaS or PaaS services by integrating itself with identity stores as Active Directory or LDAP inside organizations. IAM is designed to control Cloud resources providing access to each component, like a block storage or a computer instance.

Hope it clarifies a bit.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers above, IDCS can play role of IDP for federated login to Oracle Cloud Infrastructure console.